# dynamically loaded element different than static element although they have the same HTMl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

i am working in ASP.NET MVC 3 and constructing my html page from model as follows:

```
foreach (var item in Model.OfficialHolidaysViewModel.OfficialHolidaysForCurrentYear) 
{
   <li class="date-label"  data-id=@item.OfficialHolidayID data-date=@item.ShortDateString data-type="OfficialHoliday">
      <span class=date-text>@item.ShortDateString</span>
      <img alt="close icon" class="date-close-icon" src="/Content/Images/x_icon.png" />
   </li>
}
```

which will render and html element, for example:

```
     <li class="date-label" data-id="5" data-date="5/28/2013" data-type="OfficialHoliday">
        <span class="date-text">5/28/2013</span>
        <img alt="close icon" class="date-close-icon" src="/Content/Images/x_icon.png">
     </li>
```

and this looks like:

[image]
however, when i insert a new element with jquery:

```
$('#OfficialHolidaysCurrentYear').append(
       '<li class="date-label" data-id="' + dateID + '" data-date="' + dateString + '" data-type="' + dataType +'">' +
            '<span class="date-text">' + toRomanianLiteralFormat(dateString) + '</span>' +
            '<img alt="close icon" class="date-close-icon" src="/Content/Images/x_icon.png" />' +
       '</li>')
```

this get parameterized correctly and the result is the html:

```
        <li class="date-label" data-id="542" data-date="03/02/2013" data-type="OfficialHoliday">                                         
           <span class="date-text">02/Mar/2013</span>
          <img alt="close icon" class="date-close-icon" src="/Content/Images/x_icon.png">
        </li>
```

and this will look like in the browser:

[image]
I do not understand why they look different(notice the gap between the date text and the x icon in the first image), according to my style sheet the second one is correct....but why doesnt the first one look the same if they have the same html and css???

Btw, here is my stylesheet(.date-text has no stlyes applied):

```
.date-label
{
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #fff;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555555;
}

.date-close-icon
{
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

#### UPDATE :

This was a problem of HTML Carriage Return, see link in Aleksandr M's answer for more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it without the gap just write you code without the carriage return inside `li` like that

```
foreach (var item in Model.OfficialHolidaysViewModel.OfficialHolidaysForCurrentYear) 
{
   <li class="date-label"  data-id=@item.OfficialHolidayID data-date=@item.ShortDateString data-type="OfficialHoliday">
      <span class=date-text>@item.ShortDateString</span><img alt="close icon" class="date-close-icon" src="/Content/Images/x_icon.png" />
   </li>
}
```

See this link: http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol1/html_no3.htm

> In theory HTML doesn't pay attention to white space within your source document. In practice, your browser will interpret a carriage return as a single character of white space.

Comment: wow, it worked, but why?? Is it the browser or is Razor adding additional information somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be caused by the line break (which insert a space in the rendered html document). If you don't need that space b/w those two element then you can float both those element to left, it will ignore the space.